# How can I make an HTML form submission open in a new window?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, browser, safari

I'm trying to get an HTML form submission (feedburner email subscription) to open in a new window, rather than new tab.

However, after a bit of testing, I discovered that at least the latest versions of Chrome and Safari ignore both the target and onclick attributes, and just open the submit action in a new tab. For example,
`target="popupwindow"`, `target="_blank"` and `onsubmit="window.open("URLHERE", "popupwindow"` do not work on both my webpage and others across the net.

I'm going to assume I didn't get the memo that said that browsers just overwrite these now. Anyway, is there an alternate way of getting the form to open in a new window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="yourpage.html"  onclick="window.open('yourpage.html', 'newwindow', 'width=800, height=600'); return false;"> Your Page</a>
```

Modern browsers have this behavior blocked because it's been misused a lot in the past.

Comment: OK, thanks! That's what I tried. So there is no way at all of getting this to work?

Comment: I'm pretty new to web development so I have no other ideas if the above onclick script doesn't work. Even if you get it to work, keep in mind that a lot of browsers have a pop-up blocker.